# how to scrape and decipher a GWT page through Ajax to resubmit

Tags: gwt, submit, scrape, encryption

I am doing some screen scraping on a website and one of the pages is using GWT.  while I can read the current data on the page, I cannot update and resubmit the data since I cannot figure out how the submit data is generated. It just looks like a blob of some numbers and form values separated by |. (i.e. there are no name value pairs getting submitted.)

Has anyone figured this out? is it possible with GWT and all its obfuscation ?

Comment: Perhaps I would need to apologise for these my thoughts, but I find your endeavour humorous and a significant pinch of masochism. BTW, I did not vote you down.

Comment: Due to obfuscation and a proprietary RPC mechanism that GWT uses, I don't think this will be possible at all.

Comment: It is possible, https://github.com/GDSSecurity/GWT-Penetration-Testing-Toolset is a set of tools written to try reading some details about what a give RPC service exposes, but with some of the newer obfuscation techniques used, I'm not sure how well it will fare. A big problem you will have is not knowing the full definition of the data you are sending, so not knowing exactly what type is acceptable for what field, or when a custom serializer is used...

Comment: Thanks Colin. That was very helpful in understanding how GWT works.